# Get/display individual fields from doc.data() , eg: display the (cost :) field in doc.data()

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
firestore.collection("products").where("Product", "==", inputx)
    .get()
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        });
    })
```

here is my database

[image: database]

Comment: what is the error? this should get the result. do a `.catch()` after `.then()` and check you are getting data or not.

Comment: if you getting data you can try `doc.data().Product` or `doc.data().Cost`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy, just do `doc.data().cost`.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`get(fieldPath)`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get) method on DocumentSnapshot:

```
doc.get('Cost');
```